# Find all Critical Numbers for the Function f(x)=x^(1/5)-x^(-4/5)

Tags: calculus

Find all critical numbers for $f(x)=x^{1/5}-x^{-4/5}$. I took the derivative, getting $$\frac{1}{5}x^{-4/5}+\frac{4}{5}x^{-9/5},$$ next I need to find when $x$ is equal to zero, or when it is undefined, but I am confused on how to solve to find when $x$ is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Since

$$\frac 1 5 x^{-4/5} + \frac 4 5 x^{-9/5} = 0$$

we can clear all the fractions by multiplying by $5x^{9/5}$. This leads to

$$x + 4 = 0$$

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful, I would up vote, but I don't have enough reputation points!

Comment: You're very welcome.